# Can I play audio into the microphone?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to route the audio being played by an AVAudioPlayer(for example) to the Microphone as input?

The aim is to be able to play a sound whilst on the phone to someone. That the other person can hear.

Thanks

Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer.

There are lots of ways to route audio though the system. There a several methods of accomplishing what are describing. But Apple restricts access to the audio system while the phone is active. If you attempt to circumvent this your app will be removed from the app store.

You request the ability to use the microphone as input. A microphone is a sensor that detects movement in the air. The only way to use it as input would require that you make vibrations in the air. One could play music through the speaker on the phone that is then picked up by the microphone then that audio is shipped the the receiver via it's normal audio route.

A better way would likely be to mix your audio into the the audio recorded from the microphone and send it to the receiver then play the unmixed audio via the ear piece so the sender can hear it cleanly and the receiver can hear it mixed with a voice.  If you are developing a VOIP app you could make this happen.

RemoteIO and AudioUnit are likely the best place to start for creating a low latency audio routing system that enables you to mix microphone input with an existing audio stream.  You can read about it here.

http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/

Comment: Hi, I have tried playing a sound through the speaker at the same time, however the person at the end of the call is unable to hear the sound being played. I guess the problem ultimately is that the receiver will be using a telephone, so there will not be an app at their end to do and sub processing.

Comment: yeah, the microphone does noise cancelation too so it attempts to remove ambient sounds.  really I don't think there is a valid solution for what you are attempting. Sorry.  You could potentially create hardware to do it like a bluetooth rig but I doubt that is what you are looking for.